# Question on convergence of a pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series

Question:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence defined by $$a_1 = 2, a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3 - a_n}, \text{ if } n \geq 1$$

Does $\{a_n\}$ converge or diverge?

My solution:

I just wrote down some terms.

$a_1 = 2, a_2 = 1, a_3 = \frac{1}{2}, a_4 = 5/13, a_5 = 13/34$. Basically eventually $a_n$ will be zero, so I say this converges to $\frac{1}{3}$. What is the most simple but a good solution to prove this?

Am I allowed to discuss solutions? Because I don't understand it at all. (This is a duplicate to someone's answer where my other got closed)

The answer / duplicate.

[Let $\{a_n\}$ be defined as follows: $a_1 = 2$, $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{3-a_n}$, if $n \geq 1$. Does $\{a_n\}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188284/let-a-n-be-defined-as-follows-a-1-2-a-n1-dfrac13-a-n-if)

Essentially I just have to prove by BMCT that this is bounded below by $\frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and strictly decreasing, then this would be proven. But how did they get $\frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$ to be the bounded below value? I get how to do that afterwards though, I just dont understand this bit.

Comment: You choose the lower bound as $a'$, where $$a'=\frac1{3-a'}$$

Comment: I can choose any lower bound?

Comment: No, you choose it as the solution to the recurrence equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They chose $\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ because it is a [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{3-x}$, a point for which $f(x)=x$. You get this by solving $x=\frac{1}{3-x}$,you'll get two solutions but since the function is decreasing you'll know which one to choose.

NOTE:If $a_n=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ for some $n$ then $a_{k}=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ for all $k>n$

Comment: @Tinler No problem.